# How can I specify filename and directory for a core-dump, in Gnu/Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, coredump

I'm in the situation where my application crashes from time to time and I want to know the exact stacktrace and variables. There is boost stacktrace which gives me a trace for functions but not variable values. Setting the core dump limit with setrlimit() from my application works fine and a core dump is generated when compiled with debug symbols. What I want is a specific name for the core dump file (and a location where it is stored). Is there any way to change that inside the application without changing it for the complete system?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Because at the moment the core dump is generated, your process is already dead and the control is on the kernel which has no notion of your process's configuration anymore.

As you've found out, there's a system wide core dump handler that you can change, but it's not per-process.

However, you can install a signal handler that'll dump your process for you (although, beware if your process is multithreaded, you must stop the threads).

You might want to look at [Google Breakpad](https://github.com/google/breakpad) for a library and system to capture mini dump and send it where you want.

It's used [like that](https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/main/docs/linux_starter_guide.md)

Comment: If there is no way to tell the kernal ahead of time, then maybe using a runner to wrap the program. It could catch the crash, and `mv` the file. Containers and overlay-filesystems could also be used.

Comment: That's essentially what breakpad used to do. In your code, when you initialized the library, it would `clone` the process and run a server on the new clone waiting for the crash to happen. But that proved tricky (what if you process forks ?, or if you run multiple instance of the process ?) and they moved to a new idea, see [here](https://github.com/google/breakpad/blob/main/docs/exception_handling.md)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I don't know a way to have a private `/proc` but if you could do that, you could change `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` to whatever file pattern you want. Yet, you'd still need to be `root` for writing to this file, which might not be very safe.

Comment: Containers will allow private mounts. Or more minimally a mount-namespace.